# JavaScript - How to modify 'variable' inside function so that it does not revert to original value after function termination?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a script like this:

```
function changeValue(x){
    x = 30;
}

let a = 3;
changeValue(a);
console.log(a);
```

The above code outputs 3, but the expected output is 30. 
 Now I'm aware why this is happening, but how do I modify my code so that the changes made do not revert after the changeValue function ends? 
I have read that there are no explicit pointers in JS and I don't want to alter the value using the global variable name or by using the object approach. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

 Thank you

Comment: Best approach: return the value. Far behind: object approach plus mutation, which you say you don't like. That's about it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for reaching out. Returning the value solves my problem. But do we have any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use return, because `x` isn't an object, it's just a variable. It is discarded after the function.

Using Return:

```js
function changeValue(x){
    return 30;
}

let a = changeValue(3);
changeValue(a);
console.log("Output Is:", a);
```

Comment: thank you for reaching out. Returning the value solves my problem. But do we have any other possible solutions?

Comment: not as far as I know

Comment: thanks for showing me the wrong return statement!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, all primitive types (integers, floats, etc) are passed by value, so as other people said, for your specific use case, it's better to return the value like this:

```js
function returnValue(x) {
  return x * 10
}

let a = 3;
a = returnValue(a);
console.log(a);
```

However, if you really want to change the argument and NOT return, you need to do it with pass by reference. As I said above, it's not possible with primitive data types but is possible with objects:

```js
function changeValue(x) {
  x.value = x.value * 10;
}

let a = { value: 3 };
changeValue(a);
console.log(a.value);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it clearly, much appreciated